# How to show only top 2 and top 1 values in a grouping sets query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, rollup

I have this `PostgreSQL` table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE info (
  brand VARCHAR(255),
  segment VARCHAR(255),
  name VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO info (brand, segment, name) VALUES ('Toyota', 'SUV', 'Highlander');
INSERT INTO info (brand, segment, name) VALUES ('Toyota', 'SUV', 'Highlander');
INSERT INTO info (brand, segment, name) VALUES ('Toyota', 'SUV', 'Highlander');
INSERT INTO info (brand, segment, name) VALUES ('Toyota', 'SUV', '4Runner');
INSERT INTO info (brand, segment, name) VALUES ('Toyota', 'SUV', 'RAV4');
INSERT INTO info (brand, segment, name) VALUES ('Toyota', 'SUV', 'RAV4');
INSERT INTO info (brand, segment, name) VALUES ('Toyota', 'Sedan', 'Camry');
INSERT INTO info (brand, segment, name) VALUES ('Toyota', 'Sedan', 'Camry');
INSERT INTO info (brand, segment, name) VALUES ('Toyota', 'Sedan', 'Corolla');
INSERT INTO info (brand, segment, name) VALUES ('Toyota', 'Sedan', 'Corolla');
INSERT INTO info (brand, segment, name) VALUES ('Toyota', 'Sedan', 'Corolla');
INSERT INTO info (brand, segment, name) VALUES ('Toyota', 'Truck', 'Tacoma');
INSERT INTO info (brand, segment, name) VALUES ('Toyota', 'Truck', 'Tundra');
INSERT INTO info (brand, segment, name) VALUES ('Toyota', 'Truck', 'Tacoma');
INSERT INTO info (brand, segment, name) VALUES ('Toyota', 'Van', 'Sienna');
```

I have made this query to show the count for each grouping set and order it by the total count for each brand, segment, and name:

```
SELECT
  brand,
  segment,
  name,
  count (1) as total
FROM
  info
GROUP BY
  GROUPING SETS (
    (brand),
    (brand, segment),
    (brand, segment,name)
  )
ORDER BY
 max(count (1)) over (partition by brand) desc,
 max(count (1)) over (partition by brand,segment) desc,
 count (1) desc;
```

[This fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e4oPTvKWues8g3ut1rfsh6/0) shows how it looks like.

Now I want to select only the top 2 segments per brand, and top 1 name per brand/segment.
So the result should look like this:

| brand | segment | name | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Toyota |  |  | 15 |
| Toyota | SUV |  | 6 |
| Toyota | SUV | Highlander | 3 |
| Toyota | Sedan |  | 5 |
| Toyota | Sedan | Corolla | 3 |

I have tried using window functions but the result is not what I expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the ROW_NUMBER function as the following:

```
WITH get_grouping_set AS
(
  SELECT brand, segment, name, count(1) AS total
  FROM info
  GROUP BY GROUPING SETS 
  (
    (brand),
    (brand, segment),
    (brand, segment, name)
  )
), 
brand_segment_order AS
(
  SELECT brand, segment,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY brand ORDER BY total DESC) rn_seg
    FROM get_grouping_set
  WHERE segment IS NOT NULL AND name IS NULL
), 
joined_data AS
(
  SELECT T.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.brand, T.segment ORDER BY T.total DESC) rn 
  FROM get_grouping_set T JOIN brand_segment_order T2
  ON T.brand = T2.brand AND T.segment = T2.segment OR T.segment IS NULL
  WHERE T2.rn_seg <= 2
 )
SELECT brand, segment, name, total  
FROM joined_data 
WHERE (rn = 1 AND segment IS NULL ) OR (rn <= 2 AND segment IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY brand, MAX(Total) OVER (PARTITION BY brand, segment) DESC, 
         Total DESC, segment NULLS FIRST, name NULLS FIRST
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/MnUNFaPV)

**Another solution**.
You can use the dense_rank function ordered by the max(count) for each brand-segment group as the following:

```
WITH get_grouping_set AS
(
  SELECT brand, segment, name, count(1) AS total, 
    MAX(count(*)) over (PARTITION BY brand, segment) max_brand_segment
  FROM info
  GROUP BY GROUPING SETS 
  (
    (brand),
    (brand, segment),
    (brand, segment, name)
  )
),
brand_segment_order AS
(
  SELECT *,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY brand ORDER BY max_brand_segment DESC) segment_rank,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY brand, segment ORDER BY Total DESC) name_rank
    FROM get_grouping_set
)
SELECT brand, segment, name, total 
FROM brand_segment_order
WHERE segment_rank <= 3 AND name_rank <= 2
ORDER BY brand, max_brand_segment DESC, 
         Total DESC, segment NULLS FIRST, name NULLS FIRST
```

`WHERE segment_rank <= 3` this will retrieve two segments per brand, the plus one because the base brand (where the segment is null) is included.

`AND name_rank <= 2` this will retrieve one name per segment, the plus one because the base segment (where the name is null) is included.

The use of the dense_rank function is to get all of (segments, names) in case of ties, i.e. when there are multiple segments/ names with the same max(count).

Comment: Thanks for the response! The query works great for the example, but I'm not sure if it scales. When if I want to increase the number of `name` and  `segment` shown? For example show the top 6 names instead of top 1?

Comment: You are welcome, yes it will scale according to the row_number values, to increase the number of retrieved segments to 3 for example change  `T2.rn_seg <= 2` to `T2.rn_seg <= 3` and to increase the number of  retrieved names to 6 change `OR (rn <= 2 AND...` to `OR (rn <= 7 AND...`.

Comment: So if you want 6 names, use rn <=7, the plus 1 is to include the base segment (where name is null)

Comment: ahh true, sorry for my confusion xD Thanks again! 

I will wait a bit more before accepting, for the question to get more views in case there is a more performant way to think of. 3 CTEs are making the query quite slow

Comment: Yea, take your time, I am really interested in knowing if there is a more performant way to do this.

Comment: The second solution is much faster :) I cannot think of a more performant approach, therefore I am accepting your answer. Thanks!